# matching query does not exist What Do I make?

Tags: python, django

I wrote this code in my view I am using windows 10 and django package I have 6 products

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import Product


def product_list(request):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'product_list' : product_list}
    return render(request , 'Product/product_list.html' , context)



def product_detail(request , id):
    prodcut_detail = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'prodcut_detail' : prodcut_detail}
    return render(request , 'Product/product_detail.html' , context)
```

But he said
Product matching query does not exist. And also i added this in my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('' , views.product_list ),
    path( '<int:id>' , views.product_detail),


]
```

What Do i make?

Comment: What is your question? Also: Is this Django? (If so, please add the Django tag.) What data are you passing this view? Are you sure you have at least one product object that should have been found? Please take a look at what's recommended for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and provide enough context so that people know what the situation is, and how the code's behavior differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The line `product_detail = Product.objects.get(id=id)` in `product_detail` view is throwing this error. The reason is `product_id` that you are trying to get from DB does not exist.

Please use `get_object_or_404` so that `404` is thrown automatically if product matching `product_id` does not exist in DB.

Here is the required code:-

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def product_detail(request , id):
    product_detail = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    context = {'product_detail' : product_detail}
    return render(request , 'Product/product_detail.html', context)
```

If you don't want `404` to be thrown and do something custom when product matching `product_id` does not exist then you can use the `try / except` block. Here is the sample code:-

```
def product_detail(request , id):
    try:
        product_detail = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        # Handle the case here
        product_detail = None
    context = {'product_detail' : product_detail}
    return render(request , 'Product/product_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: it didn't work he said name 'Prodcut' is not defined

Comment: sorry. it was a typo. Its Product instead of 'Prodcut'
Updating above answer

Comment: He said that for the first answer No Product matches the given query.

Comment: And the second one worked but i wrote in `product_detail.html`  `product {{prodcut_detail}}`  But it didn't work

Comment: The problem is here    `product_detail = Product.objects.get(id=id) `            `get(id=id)`

Comment: @Ahmed check your spelling. `{{prodcut_detail}}` should probably be `{{product_detail}}`, right?